# equation solving problems

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have some equation:

$$
    veq=-2-lr-l^2r+2(r+ir^3\omega) v' + (-2+r)r^2v'^2 + (-2+r) r^2 v''==0
$$

or in Mathematica form:

```
-2 - l r - l^2 r + 
2 (r + I r^3 \[Omega]) Derivative[1][v][r] + (-2 + r) r^2 Derivative[
1][v][r]^2 + (-2 + r) r^2 (v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]
```

then generate veqexp with the code

```
veqexp[n_] := 
Normal[Series[
veq /. {v[r_] :> Sum[c[i]/r^i, {i, 1, n}], 
  v'[r_] :> Sum[-i c[i]/r^(i + 1), {i, 1, n}], 
  v''[r_] :> 
   Sum[i (i + 1) c[i]/r^(i + 2), {i, 1, n}]}, {r, \[Infinity], 
 n - 2}]];
```

I sub into this an ansatz for solution $v=\sum^n c_i r^i$. Calling this new equation in terms of the $c_i$ 'veqexp' (i.e. veq expanded). The following chunk of code can solve this for my coefficients: (note I want to solve around infinity)

```
vcoeffs[nn_] := 
Block[{}, Clear[c]; 
Do[c[i] = c[i] /. Solve[
     Limit[veqexp[nn] r^(i - 2), 
       r -> \[Infinity]] == 0, c[i]][[1]];, {i, 1, nn}]] ;
```

and out correctly pop the $c_i$ coefficients in terms of $(\omega,\ell)$ parameters of my 'veq', so far so good. The problem is that these functions  of $(\omega,\ell)$rapidly grow in size until by about the 30th Mathematica's memory gives out and dies. However if I try to calculate for a given $(\omega,\ell)=(0.1,1)$ so that each c[i] is just a number, I also hit problems to do with recursion that I have no idea about. For example

```
vcoeffs[nn_] := 
Block[{}, Clear[c]; 
Do[c[i] = 
  c[i] /. Solve[
     Limit[(veqexp[nn] /. {\[Omega] -> 0.1, l -> 1}) r^(i - 2), 
       r -> \[Infinity]] == 0, c[i]][[1]];, {i, 1, nn}]] ;
```

generates errors that read

```
 $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>
```

when I would have expected just a series of $nn$ complex coefficients which would take no memory for Mathematica to store.

Can anyone suggest a way around this? thanks

Comment: Is `ir` in your `veq` equation a single variable, or `i*r` and, in the latter case, is `i` then Mathematica's `I`? I'd prefer a non-ambiguous and above all copyable Mathematica definition instead of a pretty printing LaTeX one in this case.

Comment: If `veqexp` is an equation as you say, what does it do in ` Limit[veqexp[nn] r^(i - 2), r -> \[Infinity]]`? How do you take the limit of an equation?

Comment: $i$ is the Mathematica $I$ yes. $veqexp[nn]$ gets hit by the $r^{i-2}$ then it turns out that the only terms involving c[i] don't have negative powers of $r$ as factors, so in the limit $r\to \infty$ we get a single variable equation for c[i] to feed into Solve[...]. As I say all this works as I want, but if I try to make it specific parameters $(\omega,\ell)$ then recursion issues. Alternatively the coefficients c[i] get too big to store in memory when $i>20$.

Comment: Please add the full Mathematica definitions of veq and veqexp.

Comment: I noticed you included some definition of `veq` in a comment. It didn't resemble the above definition at all. You did remove it quickly after posting. What does that mean?

Comment: I'll second Sjoerd's request. It makes no sense to have every respondent rewriting the HTML form of veq into Mathematica.

Comment: I've tried to add the code to the OP. I used 'Copy as->Input text' not sure if that's the best way, but I can copy it in some other form if you let me know what's best.

Comment: Thanks. To confirm, Copy As > Input is a good way to do this, and the form you have is just fine now. Will have a look later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to use your ansatz, then choose the coefficients in order to kill the highest `n` powers so that your solution is well behaved at `r=Infinity`. 
The main problem I found is that I don't know how to use `CoefficientList[poly]` when the polynomial has negative powers. The following is my approach : I use `Together` because it will put the result of the substitution in the form `1/r^m \[Times] (polynomial with positive powers only)`.

This is your equation :

```
expr[v_] := -2 - l r - l^2 r + 2 (r + I r^3 \[Omega]) D[v, r] + (-2 + r) r^2
 D[v, r]^2 + (-2 + r) r^2 D[v, {r, 2}]
```

and this is my solution. I use `numQ = 1` for an exact solution, `numQ = 1.` to use inexact coefficients.

```
mysol[n_, numQ_] := First@Module[{cVec, rVec, exprAnsatz, coefficientRules},
  cVec = Subscript[c, #] & /@ Range[1, n];
  rVec = r^-# & /@ Range[1, n];
  exprAnsatz = Together[(expr[Dot[cVec, rVec]] // Expand )] ;
  coefficientRules = CoefficientRules[Together[(expr[Dot[cVec, rVec]] // Expand // Simplify)] [[2]], 
 r]  ;
 Off[Solve::ratnz];
 Solve[Thread[numQ coefficientRules[[1 ;; n, 2]] == 0], cVec]
]
```

This is keeping `\[Omega], l` symbolic (it's faster with numbers) :

```
mysol[40, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
mysol[40, 1.]; // AbsoluteTiming   
(* {15.207711, Null} *)
```

Before checking against your solution I redefined your function

```
myvcoeffs[nn_] := Block[{}, 
 Clear[c];Table[c[i] = c[i] /. Solve[Limit[veqexp[nn] r^(i - 2), r -> \[Infinity]] == 0, c[i]][[1]], {i, 1, nn}]]

(myvcoeffs[10] == mysol[10][[All, 2]]) // Simplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you possibly talk me through what is going on in your mysol[..], it seems to work nicely but I don't understand most of commands unfortunately..

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation, then ask specific questions. You can run the code inside `Module` one line a time and see what it does (though I tried to explain how it works).

Answer (score 2):

I'd form a Laurent series as an unknown "function" v[] for which we need to find derivatives. Isolate powers of r and set each to zero.

```
n = 30;
v = Series[vv[r], {r, inf, n}] /. inf -> Infinity;
vpoly = -2 - l*r - l^2*r + 
   2*(r + I*r^3*w)*D[v, r] + (-2 + r)*r^2*D[v, r]^2 + (-2 + r)*r^2*
    D[v, {r, 2}];
vpolyn = Normal[vpoly];
vpolyn = r^-Exponent[vpolyn, r, Min]*vpolyn;

coeffs = Reverse[CoefficientList[vpolyn, r]];
vars = Select[Variables[coeffs], ! FreeQ[#, vv] &];
```

We now solve for this system. There are two key observations.

(1) The jth coefficient in the list is linear in the jth derivative, and only uses other derivatives of lower order. That is, the system is in some sense triangulated. As Solve will not necessarily grasp this we may do better to solve iteratively.

(2) If, after each derivative is found, we use Together to simplify it prior to back substitution, we might keep coefficient swell to a reasonable level.

The simple loop below avails itself of these observations.

```
Timing[vtab =
   Table[var = Derivative[j][vv][Infinity];
    soln = Solve[coeffs[[j]] == 0, var][[1]];
    soln = soln /. Rule[aa_, bb_] :> Rule[aa, Together[bb]];
    coeffs = coeffs /. soln;
    var /. soln
    , {j, Length[coeffs]}];]

(* {3.38, Null} *)
```

Total size is now manageable.

```
LeafCount[vtab]

(* 29998 *)

29998
```

Here are the solutions for the first few derivatives.

```
vtab[[1 ;; 5]]

(* {(I*(l + l^2))/(2*w), (l + l^2 + 2*I*w)/(2*w^2), 
   (-6*I*l - 5*I*l^2 + 2*I*l^3 + I*l^4 + 12*w - 12*l*w - 12*l^2*w)/(4*
    w^3), 
   -((3*(6*l + 4*l^2 - 4*l^3 - 2*l^4 + 12*I*w - 22*I*l*w - 
        21*I*l^2*w + 
              2*I*l^3*w + I*l^4*w + 16*w^2))/(2*w^4)), 
   (1/(2*w^5))*(3*(60*I*l + 32*I*l^2 - 55*I*l^3 - 25*I*l^4 + 3*I*l^5 + 
           I*l^6 - 120*w + 300*l*w + 260*l^2*w - 80*l^3*w - 
      40*l^4*w + 288*I*w^2 - 
           136*I*l*w^2 - 136*I*l^2*w^2))} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also now know of another way to find the coefficients:

```
Infinitycs = Module[{n = ninfphase, c}, 
Clear[c];
veqexp = 
CoefficientList[
 Series[(-2 - l r - l^2 r + 
    2 (r + I r^3 \[Omega]) Derivative[1][v][
      r] + (-2 + r) r^2 Derivative[1][v][r]^2 + (-2 + r) r^2 (
      v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])/
   r /. {v'[r_] :> Sum[-i c[i]/r^(i + 1), {i, 1, n}], 
    v''[r_] :> 
     Sum[i (i + 1) c[i]/r^(i + 2), {i, 1, n}]}, {r, \[Infinity], 
   n - 1}], r^-1];
Do[c[i] = c[i] /. Simplify[Solve[veqexp[[i]] == 0, c[i]][[1]]]; 
Print, {i, 1, n}] ;
Table[c[i], {i, 1, n}]];
```

What is it about the functioning of 'Module' that means these coefficients $c_i$ now don't eat the memory? I thought Module just localized the variable, but would still be having to store these $n$ large coefficients in memory?